# How do I do a simple regex match and assign operation in perl? Am I on right track with: if( $file =~ m/(music\/(.*).*)$/ )

Tags: regex, perl

OK, I am reading in a file in which some of the lines contain paths to mp3's.  I know this is a simple problem, but after much much searching and experimenting, I am close, but not quite there.

A typical line in this file may look like:

```
This is some text and some more (music/rock/linkin_park/in_the_end.mp3) and some more text
```

I only want to extract the 
music/rock/linkin_park/in_the_end.mp3
portion.

Here is what I have:

```
  1 #!/usr/bin/perl -w
  2 
  3 $infile = "somefile.txt";
  4 $possibleMP3 = "";
  5 open(DAT, $infile);
  6 
  7 while (<DAT>) {
  8     chomp;
  9     $possibleMP3 = $_;
 10     if( $possibleMP3 =~ m/(music\/(.*).*)$/ )
 11     {   
 12         print "$1 \n";
 13     }
 14 }   
 15 
 16 close (DAT);
```

When a line matches, the output will look as follows

```
 usic/rock/linkin_park/in_the_end.mp3) and here is some more text and more and more.
```

The first letter is truncated, and there is trailing garbage.

Thanks for any help with this confusing, yet useful language :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure why the first digit is lost in your example.  Try this instead.

```
if( $possibleMP3 =~ m/(music(\/[^\/]+)+\.\w+)/ )
{
   print "$1 \n";
}
```

the `\w+` will match letters, digits, and _ (underscore) as many times as it can.  This lets you match other extensions.  If you don't want to allow spaces in the folders, add a `\s` to make it `(music(\/[^\/\s]+)+\.\w+)`.

After matching `music`, `(\/[^\/]+)` matches a `/` and then all the characters that aren't `/`.  The `+` makes it match multiple layers of folders.  The `\.\w+` matches the extension.

Comment: worked perfectly.  Can you please explain this in plain english for us mortals :p.  I can foresee  this type of thing coming up again.  Thanks !

Comment: @Chirs D.  I added an explanation (and corrected for multiple folders).  I'd be glad to explain further if you have any questions.

Comment: You might consider using another delimeter character for the pattern match, since `/` will be in the regex. Also, `\.\w+` will match any file extension.

Comment: @Chris D.: Go to CPAN and install http://search.cpan.org/~gsullivan/YAPE-Regex-Explain-4.01/Explain.pm (Regex::Explain).  Then Perl can explain complicated regular expressions to you in plain old English.  It's an easy module to use.

Comment: Thanks to all who have helped me to understand this.

Answer (score 1):

The truncated first letter is weird, but the trailing garbage is simply because you use `.*`, and never close it off. `*` and `+` are greedy, and use up all the characters they can, unless you tell them not to. Since `.` matches any character, it will match the rest of the string.

This would probably suffice:

```
$possibleMP3 =~ m{(music/[\w/]+\.mp3)}i
```

I.e. close the match with `mp3`, use `{}` instead of `//` to make it easier on the eyes, and use `i` option to match case insensitively (if appropriate in your case).

Answer (score 1):

Try to change regexp to this:

```
if( $possibleMP3 =~ m/\(music\/([^\)]*)\)/ )
```

Answer (score 1):

music.*?mp3 - relies that path begins with music and ends with mp3. .*? - match anything in between but make match as short as possible

Comment: But that will also match `"I really like music. Here is a list of my mp3's"` ;)